# How we can set an image as default value in assets field

Tags: craft-features

I have a field for upload an image in asset field. Can we set a default image in this field. Means when I create a new entry a default image has been already selected in asset field.

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible, but the way I handle this is to have a Global called "Missing Image Fallback" inside a "Generic" Global field set, and then when I need to reference an image I use the following twig:

```
{% set image = entry.myImageField.first ?? generic.missingImageFallback.first %}
```

That will assign the first myImageField asset to 'image' if it's been filled in, but fall back to the generic global field if not.